# Integrating Old Javascript Functions into React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently using this package of Javascript on my website.  And I need to be able to use it in the app that I'm trying to build (I'm VERY new to react-native--a PHP, javascript developer here).

How do I integrate it? Do I have to convert it or is it possible to just include it and call the functions?  I have no idea. Sigh. I've searched but I didn't find anything that answered my question--though that could be because I'm new to RN and don't know what the heck I'm doing :(.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

To use the functions, I currently just call them with the second line in Javascript:

```
var strINeedHashed = "Hash Me Please";

var hash = hex_sha256(strINeedHashed);
```

Here's the JS I need access to:

```
var chrsz = 8;  /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode  */
function safe_add (x, y) {
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}
function S (X, n) {return ( X >>> n ) | (X << (32 - n));}
function R (X, n) {return ( X >>> n );}
function Ch(x, y, z) {return ((x & y) ^ ((~x) & z));}
function Maj(x, y, z) {return ((x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z));}
function Sigma0256(x) {return (S(x, 2) ^ S(x, 13) ^ S(x, 22));}
function Sigma1256(x) {return (S(x, 6) ^ S(x, 11) ^ S(x, 25));}
function Gamma0256(x) {return (S(x, 7) ^ S(x, 18) ^ R(x, 3));}
function Gamma1256(x) {return (S(x, 17) ^ S(x, 19) ^ R(x, 10));}
function core_sha256 (m, l) {
    var K = new Array(0x428A2F98,0x71374491,0xB5C0FBCF,0xE9B5DBA5,0x3956C25B,0x59F111F1,0x923F82A4,0xAB1C5ED5,0xD807AA98,0x12835B01,0x243185BE,0x550C7DC3,0x72BE5D74,0x80DEB1FE,0x9BDC06A7,0xC19BF174,0xE49B69C1,0xEFBE4786,0xFC19DC6,0x240CA1CC,0x2DE92C6F,0x4A7484AA,0x5CB0A9DC,0x76F988DA,0x983E5152,0xA831C66D,0xB00327C8,0xBF597FC7,0xC6E00BF3,0xD5A79147,0x6CA6351,0x14292967,0x27B70A85,0x2E1B2138,0x4D2C6DFC,0x53380D13,0x650A7354,0x766A0ABB,0x81C2C92E,0x92722C85,0xA2BFE8A1,0xA81A664B,0xC24B8B70,0xC76C51A3,0xD192E819,0xD6990624,0xF40E3585,0x106AA070,0x19A4C116,0x1E376C08,0x2748774C,0x34B0BCB5,0x391C0CB3,0x4ED8AA4A,0x5B9CCA4F,0x682E6FF3,0x748F82EE,0x78A5636F,0x84C87814,0x8CC70208,0x90BEFFFA,0xA4506CEB,0xBEF9A3F7,0xC67178F2);
    var HASH = new Array(0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A, 0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19);
    var W = new Array(64);
    var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
    var T1, T2;
    /* append padding */
    m[l >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - l % 32);
    m[((l + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = l;
    for ( var i = 0; i<m.length; i+=16 ) {
        a = HASH[0]; b = HASH[1]; c = HASH[2]; d = HASH[3]; e = HASH[4]; f = HASH[5]; g = HASH[6]; h = HASH[7];
        for ( var j = 0; j<64; j++) {
            if (j < 16) W[j] = m[j + i];
            else W[j] = safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(Gamma1256(W[j - 2]), W[j - 7]), Gamma0256(W[j - 15])), W[j - 16]);
            T1 = safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(h, Sigma1256(e)), Ch(e, f, g)), K[j]), W[j]);
            T2 = safe_add(Sigma0256(a), Maj(a, b, c));
            h = g; g = f; f = e; e = safe_add(d, T1); d = c; c = b; b = a; a = safe_add(T1, T2);
        }
        HASH[0] = safe_add(a, HASH[0]); HASH[1] = safe_add(b, HASH[1]); HASH[2] = safe_add(c, HASH[2]); HASH[3] = safe_add(d, HASH[3]); HASH[4] = safe_add(e, HASH[4]); HASH[5] = safe_add(f, HASH[5]); HASH[6] = safe_add(g, HASH[6]); HASH[7] = safe_add(h, HASH[7]);
    }
    return HASH;
}
function str2binb (str) {
  var bin = Array();
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
    bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i%32);
  return bin;
}
function binb2hex (binarray) {
  var hexcase = 0; /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase */
  var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
    str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) + hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
  }
  return str;
}
function hex_sha256(s){return binb2hex(core_sha256(str2binb(s),s.length * chrsz));}
```

Comment: you can use this syntax in react native, just check how would you export these functions, either you want to make functional components or class components(ES6). Check the libraries you are using because many of the normal javascript libraries do not work in React Native, so you would have to find an alternative for them.

Answer (score 0):

if that is working javascript, you just add it to your project's code.

Fastest, a bit ugly way, is to include that code in the file where you using it. More proper way would be to make of file for that and include es6 exports for functions that you need to access.

Answer (score 0):

React Native uses JavaScript, so in theory if you function is written in JavaScript you should have no issues integrating it into your React Native project. Just simply add your old function to the React Native project and just call it as you normally would :)